# Convert Object Array to another type array using Reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

I have an object array and I want to convert it to a specific type array. I have the type to convert it into which I get at run time. But I am having a problem doing the actual conversion.

If I use the Convert.ChangeType, I get the error that Object must implement IConvertible

The Array.ConvertAll is template based and requires that I pass the destination type as a template which I only know at run time. I even tried to do use reflection to call this method but I cannot pass the lambda expression as an argument to the MethodInfo.Invoke method.

Any Ideas?

Right I have the following which is not working:

```
Type convertTo = GetFinalType();
Object[] objArr = GetObjectArray();
var arr = Array.ConvertAll(objArr,elem=> Convert.ChangeType(elem,convertTo));
```

Comment: How is this "not working?" Is an exception thrown?

Comment: @Mark: *"I get the error that Object must implement IConvertible"*

Comment: The line 
var arr = Array.ConvertAll(objArr,elem=> Convert.ChangeType(elem,convertTo));
does not compile because it needs the target type as a template e.g 
Array.ConvertAll<T1,T2>(objArr,elem=> Convert.ChangeType(elem,convertTo)); .. I only have T2 at runtime

Comment: @shake: What kinds of objects are you storing in this array?

Comment: Its nothing special .. just a regular class object. I even tried (MyClass[])objArr and get the error {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'MyClass[]'."}

Comment: @shake in that case, I agree with the answer from @cdhowie. You need to implment this interface on any type with which you will be using this method.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
var finalType = GetFinalType();
var objArr = GetObjectArray();
var arr = Array.CreateInstance(finalType, objArr.Length);
Array.Copy(objArr, arr, objArr.Length);
```

That's untested, but it should work.  It's more compact and doesn't (really) use reflection.

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is easier. Thanks for the comment. I should have thought of that a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

You are close; does the following work, or was objType a typo?

```
Type convertTo = GetFinalType();
Object[] objArr = GetObjectArray();
var arr = Array.ConvertAll(objArr,elem=> Convert.ChangeType(elem, convertTo));
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it the worst way possible but I managed it somehow. I created a new class

```
public class Tools
{
    public static T[] Convert<T>(object[] objArr)
    {
        IList<T> list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var o in objArr)
        {
            list.Add((T)o);
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And where I needed the conversion, I used:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Tools).GetMethod("Convert");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { t });

object o = generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { objArr });

var m =  Convert.ChangeType(o,typeof(tArr));
```

Where

```
t = typeof(MyClass); 
tArr = typeof(MyClass[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is failing because some object in your array is not a primitive type, or is not something that implements the `IConvertible` interface  You cannot use `Convert.ChangeType()` on such objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that worked for me:

```
public static T[] CastArrayToType<T>(object[] collection)
{
    return Array.ConvertAll<object, T>(
        collection,
        delegate(object prop)
        {
            return (T)prop;
        }
    );
}
```